# Which country's law applies when scraping / crawling web pages?

Tags: internet, software, international

I'm interested in the legal aspects of gathering (scraping) data from web pages with web robots / scrapers / crawlers. I am not sure which country's law applies in the case that a website is hosted in one country and accessed from a crawler program hosted in another country. Does the situation change if there are user publications on the website, from users living in none of the two countries?

Comment: Possibly both, and more besides.  Every country can decide when to apply its own laws.  
 What they can practically do to enforce them is another question.

Comment: Yes. The short answer is that the question doesn't have an easy answer. Somebody files a suit somewhere in a particular court and that court follows its jurisdiction's choice of law rules a body of law that is neither uniform nor consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory the law of every country where the web page can be accessed as well as the author’s and scraper’s location and citizenship(s) as well as the server’s location(s).